# How to produce dynamic div id? in PHP/JAVASCRIPT/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax code that displays data from table columns when a data is chosen from the dropdown.

surveycontent.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","hay.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

ajax.php. I have a textbox that generates dropdowns based on how many the user input

```
    if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main == 1){
        $i = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++)
        {
            $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");
            echo "<form><b id='labelquestion_dropdown'>Question #". $i."</b>";
            echo "<select id='question_dropdown".$i."' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this.value)' style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns".$i."'>";
            echo "<option selected>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                    echo "<option value='$row[question_id]'>";
                    echo $row["questiontitle"];
                    echo "</option>";

            }
            echo "</select></form>";
            echo  "<div id='txtHint'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>";
            echo "<br />";

        }

        echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>";

        echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues_Cat();'>Add Question</a> | ";
    echo "<a href='#del_question' onclick='return delQues();'>Delete Question</a>";
}
```

hay.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','imetrics') or die ("Cannot connect to database");
if(!$con){
    echo ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$id= isset($_GET["q"])?intval($_GET["q"]):"";

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id = '".$id."'");

function displayOption($i, $value, $answer_type) {
    if($value == null) {
        return;
    }

    if($answer_type == "radiobutton") {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="rinput" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES).'">'.htmlspecialchars($value).'<br>';
    } else if($answer_type == "checkbox") {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cinput['.$i.']" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES).'">'.htmlspecialchars($value).'<br>';
    }
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    for($i = 1; $i<=10; ++$i) {
        displayOption($i, $row["Option_$i"], $row['answer_type']);
    }
}

?>
```

I have a textbox that generates dropdowns based on the user input. For example, I generated 3 dropdowns, I need to make it possible that hay.php will display data for each of the dropdowns when clicked. Atm it's only showing 1 whichever dropdown I use to choose from. I think the problem is I only have 1 id for the `<div id='textHint'>` or is it a different problem?

Comment: DOM elements must have unique ID attributes if they are to have an an ID at all - you cannot have multiple divs with the ID `txtHint`

Comment: yes agree with @RamRaider You cant assign mulitiple same id.
i Suggest you to assign this as class and check as `document.getElementsByClassName(txtHint)` or `$(".txtHint").val()`

Comment: The div part is where I display the data from hay.php to start with. I need it to display under each dropdown. Can you show me sample of code on how I will put that code sir? @JaykumarGondaliya

Comment: I changed my document.getElementByID to document.getElementsByClassName but it didn't display anything it all when i chose data from dropdown @RamRaider

Comment: @Jola You Mention here **I need it to display under each dropdown**

Comment: Yes and I also think that's my problem because it's only displaying under 1st dropdown. Then whenever I choose from the second dropdown it replaces the data under the first dropdown which it shouldn't do. IT should display under second dropdown while the data under the first dropdown is also there. Can we have a chat sir?
 It'll be easier to explain there @JaykumarGondaliya

Comment: So it means you would like to create dynamic multiple Dropdown, AM i Right?Just Give me 20 Minutes.I leave at office and Day End

Comment: I've already created that textbox to generate dynamic dropdowns, its just it only triggers the ajax part once when datas are chosen from multiple dropdowns. I can explain it better when you get home sir thank you @JaykumarGondaliya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "hacky" way you could do this ( if I understood the problem correctly ) would be to assign a unique id to the various generated DIV elements and supply that ID as a second argument to your ajax function.

```
/* note 2nd parameter - id */
function showUser(str,id) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                /* use id supplied */
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","hay.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And the PHP code

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++ ){
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");


    echo "
    <form>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown'>Question #{$i}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$i}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$i}'>
            <option selected>Select";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];
    }

    echo "
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id='txtHint{$i}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    <br />";
}
```

You might notice the missing `</option>` from the above - it's not necessary to use it so I tend to omit it.

Comment: Sir I'm getting this error, unexpected 'showUser' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\imetricslatest\ajax.php on line 35. I think this part is causing that onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" @RamRaider

Comment: :) no problem - I was just trying to find the error but seems to work fine here. Like I say - it is a bit "hacky" but if it works then it can't be all bad

Comment: It's pretty amazing bro :) I was wondering if you could help me out with one more problem. Like give me ideas. Maybe chat? @RamRaider

Comment: what's the other problem?

Comment: Duplicating a div with onclick button @RamRaider

Comment: to make an exact copy you can use `cloneNode` ~ beware of cloned IDs though!

Comment: Not exact. I was hoping different id's. Therees also other divs inside the div i want to duplicate and i want those divs with diferrent ids too @RamRaider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147854/discussion-between-ramraider-and-jola).

Comment: Hey sir can I chat with you again it's regarding this answer you just helped me with. Very very very similar @RamRaider

Comment: Sir @RamRaider? :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay! If You wanna to  put your div in Drop-down.
You may try this in Your code
`echo  "<option class="HINT"><div id='txtHint'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div></option>";`

```html
<select>
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
<option>four</option>
<option><div>THIS IS DIV</div></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't want to put div in my dropdown. I want it to display under in all dropdowns and not just 1 in total.